# Configure Rails Logger to store full stack trace by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

By default, I only get a partial stack trace of an errors.  How do I configure a Rails app to log the entire stack trace in the server logs?

I'm looking for a change I can make at the configuration level, as opposed to diving into individual classes and logging the full backtrace by rescuing the exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put your app on the highest log level (which is ":debug"), you'd get what want:

[Rails guides on log level](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels)